# Singleton PHP on multiple controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I created one class (ParseDAO.php) and made it singleton with this method:

```
public static function getInstance(){
    if (self::$instance == null) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Then I created 2 controllers. One to login stuff (LoginController.php) and another do dashboard stuff (DashboardController.php)

In LoginController.php I use this code and it works perfectly:

```
    $instance = ParseDAO::getInstance();

    $loginResponse = $instance->loginParse($request->get('userName'), $request->get('password'));

    if($loginResponse == true){
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
    else {
        return view('login.erroLogin');
    }
```

At DashboardController I have this code:

```
    $instance = ParseDAO::getInstance();

    $userId = $instance->getUserId();
```

This second line just returns the objectId form parse. If I put this line on loginController.php it returns the correct Id, but at DashboardController.php (where I need this data) nothing returns.
It's like another instance was created even using singleton.

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Follow the code of loginParse and getUserId:

```
 /**
 * Method login
 */
public function loginParse($username, $password){
    if($username != null && $password != null){
        try {
            self::$user = ParseUser::logIn($username, $password);
            return true;
        }catch (ParseException $error){
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * @return getUserId
 */
public function getUserId(){
    return self::$user->getObjectId();
}
```

And this is the constructor code (with the true keys):

```
public function __construct()
{
    ParseClient::initialize('xxx','xxx','xxx');
    self::$user = new ParseUser();
}
```

Comment: What is the code for `loginParse` and `getUserId`?

Answer (score 1):

Singletons allow for code from a single execution to use the same instance. On every execution (page load), a new instance is created. Every call to `ParseDAO::getInstance()` will return the same instance, but only within that execution context.

Without seeing the code in `loginParse` and `getUserId`, what is most likely occurring is that you are storing information in the `ParseDAO` class. That information would be kept during the same execution context, but would disappear on the next execution (because it's a new instance).

You'll have to use [Sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session) to persist information across multiple executions.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Service Container offers a quick and easy way to bind a class as a singleton without the need to implement that pattern yourself. So you can use this to register you singleton with the service container:

```
app()->bind('ParseDAO', function ($app) {
    return new ParseDAO;
});
```

And then you can use this to access that instance:

```
$instance = app('ParseDAO');
```

That will make sure you always get the same instance. You can read more about singletons and the Laravel Service container in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding).